# Is there any difference in the implementation of these three validation methods?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Core Data is calling these methods in certain situations:

```
- (BOOL)validateForInsert:(NSError **)outError;
- (BOOL)validateForUpdate:(NSError **)outError;
- (BOOL)validateForDelete:(NSError **)outError;
```

I wonder if they're doing anything different, or if they're essentially doing the exact same things.

As far as I know, these methods call the `-validateValue:forKey:error:` method once for every property.

The only difference I can imagine is in the .validateForDelete: method. I see no reason why to validate an object when it shall be deleted, except for applying delete rules, probably only in the case of the DENY rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are lifecycle validation methods. There are many situations that the question of validation differs depending on the object's state.  For example:

- Don't delete unless child X is nil
- Don't insert unless value X is unique
- Don't update unless child Y has been set

These methods give finer grain control over the integrity of the object hierarchy.